# Группировка по последовательным повторам mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает.
Есть таблица вот такого содержание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу получить данные типа

| datetime | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-26 21:24:01 | 0 |
| 2023-02-26 21:12:02 | 1 |
| 2023-02-26 21:06:02 | 0 |
| 2023-02-26 20:48:01 | 1 |

т.е. нужны только периоды изменения значения, их повторы не нужны.
Как составить запрос чтобы получить желаемое и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: версию СУБД напишите подробнее

Comment: @teran 8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server

Answer (score 2):

Тут путает именно то, что дата отображена по убыванию и не понятно как записи вносились в базу. Скорее это какой-то журнал и тут надо поймать изменение `status` со следующей датой, хотя сути это не меняет. Автор уже ответил на свой вопрос, а я просто оставлю здесь свой вариант решения:

```
-- искомая таблица
CREATE TABLE testTable (
  date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  status int NOT NULL
);

-- данные
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:24:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:21:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:18:02', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:15:02', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:12:02', 1);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:09:01', 1);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:06:02', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:03:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 21:00:02', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:57:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:54:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:51:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:48:01', 1);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:45:02', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:42:01', 0);
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('2023-02-26 20:39:01', 0);

-- выборка
SELECT 
  t.date,
  t.status
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      date,
      status,
      LAG(status) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS nextStatus -- следующий статус
    FROM testTable
  ) t
WHERE
  t.status != t.nextStatus -- либо есть разница
  OR t.nextStatus IS NULL -- либо последняя
ORDER BY
  t.date DESC;
```

Comment: да, это журнал с id, датой, статусом и пользователем. Выборка по пользователю, а по id просто в обратном порядке отсортировано, чтобы получать выборку с актуальных данных. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

решил примерно так

```
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT status
         , date
         , (LAG(status, 1) OVER ()) AS last_status 
    FROM data
    ORDER BY date DESC
)
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE status <> last_status 
    OR last_status IS NULL;
```

Запрос включает функцию `LAG` (вроде как с 8.0.22 доступна), благодаря которой получаем значение прошлой строки.
Весь результат в табличное выражение.
В выборке сравниваем текущий `status` с прошлым.

Comment: вам бы сортировку по дате сделать в окне, а из цте убрать, и так  же сделать во внешнем запросе